# File polling in network shared folder using Spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

We are working on file polling using Spring Integration in our project. Have implemented polling process using file:inbound-channel-adapter. was able to poll files from local directory. But as per requirements, we have to poll files from Network shared folder, like \dzmn02xf00001\28fted$\data\portrait\input\Loadspecifications.

can you please help us if any one of you implemented file polling in network shared folder using Spring integration? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For *nix operating systems, NFS shares should just work out of the box.

For `Windows` shares you need to use the [SMB extension](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-smb) - but that needs to be brought up to date to work with Spring Integration 4.0.x; it should work ok with 3.0.x and earlier.

Comment: We have our shared folder in Windows server. As you said we have to use Spring integration SMB schema to poll, but I couldnt find SMB folder and schemas under http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/. is there any way to implement it with out this schema. Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: It's an extension project, not part of the core - I provided the link in the answer.